# Creating prefabs for AugmentedImages in ARCore + Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I've been trying to create prefabs to render on top of images using models from the asset store and my own script but the prefabs I create are not being accepted for the prefab field present in `AugmentedImageExampleController.cs`. I am not sure where exactly my prefabs are going wrong and would really appreciate any help in the right direction.

Comment: What do you mean they are not accepted? You have a prefab but you can not drag it to AugmentedImageVisualizerPrefab field in the inspector or you drag them but they are not visualized ?

Comment: When I drag the prefab into the field I get the circle a cross inside, which doesn't let me change the prefab. However, I am able to drop objects into the FitToScan Overlay field.

Comment: You cant drag gameobject prefab to AugmentedImageVisualizerPrefab tab. It has to be a script. What you have to do is go to AugmentedImageVisualizer  script ant create a `public Gameobject FromAssetStorePrefab;`  and then visualize it however you want.

Comment: Will test this right away and let you know :)

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot.
Also sorry for the late reply

Comment: No problem glad i could help.